# How do I halt the current execution in Scilab?

Tags: scilab

I'm working with a fairly large dataset and any time I perform an operation, if I forget to include the semi-colon at the end of the statement it takes several minutes because it outputs all the data to the console window as it goes. How do I halt execution of the current statement?

I've tried using Ctrl-C like in MATLAB, as well as using the Abort and Interrupt options in the Control menu, none of which seem to be working. Is this a bug, or am I missing something? I'm running on Windows 8 64-bit in case that helps.

Answer (score 1):

To halt execution, press Ctrl-C in the *console window* of Scilab. This will display

```
Type 'resume' or 'abort' to return to standard level prompt.

-1->
```

Entering `abort` abandons the computation completely. Entering `resume` resumes it.

Answer (score 0):

I did not check it but [this tutorial](https://p2pu.org/en/groups/getting-started-with-scilab/content/session-1-scilab-environment/) gives as option the `ESC` key

> "To abort a command midway without executing it, press the Esc key on the keyboard."